# Word Counter in c doesnt work

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a c code like below.
I want to count the number of words in a text delimited with a delimiter.
The code compiles but stops.
What is the problem?
This is my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int WordCount(char *text,char delimiter)
{
    char *s;
    int count = 0;
    strcpy(s,text);
    while(*s){
        if(*s==delimiter){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *line = "a,b,c,d,e";

    printf("%d\n",WordCount(line,','));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You arent incrementing your pointer s to actually MOVE through the string either.  Im pretty sure that your WordCount routine might be an infinite loop situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to increment the pointer `s`, thus you had an infinite loop, and instead of copying the string (for which you would need to allocate memory), just let it point to the input.

```
int WordCount(char *text,char delimiter)
{
    char *s = text;
    int count = 0;
    // strcpy(s,text);
    while(*s){
        if(*s==delimiter){
            count++;
        }
        ++s;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char *s;
int count = 0;
strcpy(s,text);
```

`s` is an uninitialized pointer not an array object.

Answer (score 2):

`char *s;` - allocate memory for `s` in stack or heap.

Mistakes in your program

- All variable must be initalized while declaring.
- Valid Memory should be allocated/assigned to a pointer variable.
- Indefinite Loop, its checking always the first character of the string.

Modify your code like below

```
...
char *s = NULL;
int count = 0;
s = text; 
while(*s);
{
    if (*s == delimiter)
    {
        count++;
    }
    s++;
}
...
```

Comment: He doenst need to make a copy, thus why allocate?

Comment: So now you are always updating s with s++, and if s[count] == the delimeter, you essentially are double counting, because you increment count also then referencing using s[count]